# Java consecutive method calls

Tags: java, methods

So I've seen, in many places, calling methods of a class like:

```
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
obj.addX(3).addY(4).setSomething("something").execute();
```

I don't think I completely understand how that works.  Is each method independent of each other, so the above is equal to:

```
obj.addX(3);
obj.addY(4);
obj.addSomething("something");
obj.execute();
```

Or are they designing their class structure in some other fashion that allows for this.  If they are how are they designing their classes to support this?

Also, does that have a specific name?  Or is this just calling methods on a class?

Comment: @dlev - Fluent interfaces are more general than this, I think; the better term would be [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) (or _method cascading_).

Comment: @TedHopp Fair point, though in the vast majority of cases I've seen, method chaining is primarily used in support of fluent interfaces. Nonetheless I'll remove my erroneous comment :)

Comment: Each method has `return this;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be method chaining. It can do one of two things.

1. Each call to a method returns `this` which allows you to continue to call methods on the original instance.

   ```
   public class SomeClass
   {
       private int _x = 0;
       private int _y = 0;
       private String _something = "";

       public SomeClass addX(int n)
       {
           _x += n;
           return this;
       }

       public SomeClass addY(int n)
       {
           _y += n;
           return this;
       }

       public SomeClass setSomething(String something)
       {
           _something = something;
           return this;
       }

       // And so on, and so on, and so on...
   }
   ```
2. Each method call returns a new instance of the class with everything copied/updated appropriately. This makes the class immutable (so you don't accidentally modify something that you didn't mean to).

   ```
   public class SomeClass
   {
       private int _x = 0;
       private int _y = 0;
       private String _something = "";

       public SomeClass(int x, int y, String something)
       {
           _x = x;
           _y = y;
           _something = something;
       }

       public SomeClass addX(int n)
       {
           return new SomeClass(_x + n, _y, _something);
       }

       public SomeClass addY(int n)
       {
           return new SomeClass(_x, _y + n, _something);
       }

       public SomeClass setSomething(String something)
       {
           return new SomeClass(_x, _y, something);
       }

       // And so on, and so on, and so on...
   }
   ```

Some people have also mentioned Fluent Interfaces. Fluent Interfaces utilize method chaining to create an API that provides something along the lines of a Domain Specific Language which can make code read much more clearly. In this case, your example doesn't quite qualify.

Answer (score 2):

they modify object's state and return the same object back mostly

```
class Number{
 int num;

 public Number add(int number){
     num+=number;
     return this;
 }

}
```

you can call it like

```
new Number().add(1).add(2);
```

most of the time the use case is to return new Object to support immutability

Comment: Note that it is not necessarily the case that the same object is returned. It's completely plausible that a new object is constructed each time (if, say, the class is meant to be immutable). Certainly when this is used as a builder pattern I would hope the same object is returned, though :)

Comment: @dlev ofcourse this is just basic example, the main use case is in immutable objects

Answer (score 1):

Each of those methods return an instance. For example, the call to

```
obj.addX(3)
```

will return the same instance `obj`, so the call

```
obj.addX(3).addY(4)
```

will be equivalent to

```
obj.addY(4)
```

This is called [**method chaining**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

The methods are implemented like this:

```
public SomeClass addX(int i) {
    // ...
    return this; // returns the same instance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Test1 abc = new Test1();
        abc.add1(10, 20).sub1(40, 30).mul1(23, 12).div1(12, 4);
    }
    
    public Test1 add1(int a, int b)
    {
        int c = a + b;
        System.out.println("Freaking Addition output : "+c);
        return this;
    }
    
    public Test1 sub1(int a, int b)
    {
        int c = a - b;
        System.out.println("Freaking subtraction  output : "+c);
        return this;
    }
    
    public Test1 mul1(int a, int b)
    {
        int c = a * b;
        System.out.println("Freaking multiplication  output : "+c);
        return this;
    }

    public Test1 div1(int a, int b)
    {
        int c = a / b;
        System.out.println("Freaking divison  output : "+c);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not appear to answer the questions that were asked. I you beleive it does, please [edit] your answer to address the specific questions that the OP has raised.